# How can I see how the browser percent-encoded my URL? (which is not visible on address bar)

Tags: html, url, uri, url-encoding, percent-encoding

When I paste a url containing some reserved characters to the address bar of IE, FF, Chrome, I see that it displays it as it is but as far as I understand in uses percent-encoding in the background.

How can I see in IE, FF and Chrome how the browser encoded the url?

Is it possible?

P.S: The reason I want to check this is I have a feeling my url is encoded differently in IE and FF and Chrome -so that it only works in IE.

Comment: did you try looking in the webserver logs?

Answer (score 2):

Put the URL into an HTML page, ie,

```
    <a href="www.example.com?param=text with reserved characters">click</a>
```

Load in each browser, right-click, copy URL, paste into a text app or the address bar.

You can also use:

```
    <script>
    alert(encodeURIComponent('the text you want to see encoded'));
    </script>
```

Answer (score 2):

Copy the URL from the browser’s address bar and paste it into a text document.