# Keep spaces in URLs without encoding them

Tags: url, url-rewriting, urlencode, url-encoding

As Stack Overflow seems to be unable to create links from URLs that have spaces in them, copy and paste this URL into your browser.

```
http://grooveshark.com/#!/search/song?q=we will rock you
```

It does **not** redirect you to `...song?q=we%20will%20rock%20you` or anything like that.
The spaces just simply stay there. When I first saw this, it looked so foreign to me. How is this achieved?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe they use javascript to set the contents of the url bar. You can use something like Live HTTP Headers to confirm that the browser definitely sends a request with %20 encoded spaces.

Answer (score 0):

It’s a browser setting. The browser decodes the URL, to make it more readable for humans.

If you copy the URL from the browser’s address bar and paste it into a text document, you’ll see that the space characters are percent-encoded.

See [How can I see how the browser percent-encoded my URL? (which is not visible on address bar)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18586870/1591669)