# Inexplicable behavior when copying URL from Firefox address bar

Tags: url, firefox, parameters

Can someone explain to me the following behavior:

When I copy a specific URL from Firefox and paste it to Notepad++ (or Stack Overlow) some parameters changed. I can't post the orginial URL but it's something like this:

In address bar:

```
https://xxx.xxx-xxxx.de/xxxxx//xxxxx?project=xxxxl&query=xxxx&keyname=OBJNAME&keyvalue=05-(G)28-01-008
```

But Notepad++ and Stack Overflow shows me this:

```
https://xxx.xxx-xxxx.de/xxxxx//xxxxx?project=xxxx&query=xxxxx&keyname=OBJNAME&keyvalue=05%2D%28G%2928%2D01%2D008
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This URI is percent-encoded.

See the URI standard: [Percent-Encoding](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-2.1). There are various reasons why something could be percent-encoded (sometimes it’s required, sometimes optional; sometimes it changes the meaning, sometimes not).

[Some browsers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30012739/1591669) display the URL *after* decoding the percent-encoded parts. This is typically done for usability reasons: it’s nicer to see `https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ö` instead of `https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C3%96`.

Copy-pasting the URL from the address bar to some other place [is one way](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18611595/1591669) to see the actual URL (with percent-encoding).